# SwiftUI out of index when deleting an array element in ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui

I looked through different questions here, but unfortunately I couldn't find an answer. This is my code:

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
...
let contentView = ContentView(elementHolder: ElementHolder(elements: ["abc", "cde", "efg"]))
...
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
class ElementHolder: ObservableObject {

    @Published var elements: [String]

    init(elements: [String]) {
        self.elements = elements
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var elementHolder: ElementHolder

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            ForEach(self.elementHolder.elements.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                SecondView(elementHolder: self.elementHolder, index: index)
            }

        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {

    @ObservedObject var elementHolder: ElementHolder
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("...", text: self.$elementHolder.elements[self.index])
            Button(action: {
                self.elementHolder.elements.remove(at: self.index)
            }) {
                Text("delete")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When pressing on the delete button, the app is crashing with a Index out of bounds error.

There are two strange things, the app is running when

1) you remove the `VStack` and just put the `ForEach` into the `body` of the `ContentView.swift` or

2) you put the code of the `SecondView` directly to the `ForEach`

Just one thing: I really need to have the `ObservableObject`, this code is just a simplification of another code.

**UPDATE**

I updated my code and changed `Text` to a `TextField`, because I cannot pass just a string, I need a connection in both directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is possible solution - make body of `SecondView` undependable of `ObservableObject`.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 - no crash

```
struct SecondView: View {

    @ObservedObject var elementHolder: ElementHolder
    var index: Int
    let value: String

    init(elementHolder: ElementHolder, index: Int) {
        self.elementHolder = elementHolder
        self.index = index
        self.value = elementHolder.elements[index]
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(value)     // not refreshed on delete
            Button(action: {
                self.elementHolder.elements.remove(at: self.index)
            }) {
                Text("delete")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another possible solution is do not observe `ElementHolder` in `SecondView`... for presenting and deleting it is not needed - also no crash

```
struct SecondView: View {

    var elementHolder: ElementHolder // just reference
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(self.elementHolder.elements[self.index])
            Button(action: {
                self.elementHolder.elements.remove(at: self.index)
            }) {
                Text("delete")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** variant of `SecondView` for text field (only changed is text field itself)

```
struct SecondViewA: View {

    var elementHolder: ElementHolder
    var index: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("", text: Binding(get: { self.elementHolder.elements[self.index] },
                set: { self.elementHolder.elements[self.index] = $0 } ))
            Button(action: {
                self.elementHolder.elements.remove(at: self.index)
            }) {
                Text("delete")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Solution 2 is nice, but I have a TextField, not just a Text ;) (that's the problem of simplifying code ;)). Solution 1 then has the same problem :( I'll update my code example.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: would it work with the `onDelete` `modifier` for `ForEach` other than dedicated button for to delete? @Asperi

Comment: Does this still work? It crashes for me on Xcode 12.5...

Answer (score 8):

The issue arises from the order in which updates are performed when clicking the delete button.

On button press, the following will happen:

1. The `elements` property of the element holder is changed
2. This sends a notification through the `objectWillChange` publisher that is part of the `ElementHolder` and that is declared by the `ObservableObject` protocol.
3. The views, that are subscribed to this publisher receive a message and will update their content.

   1. The SecondView receives the notification and updates its view by executing the `body` getter.
   2. The ContentView receives the notification and updates its view by executing the `body` getter.

To have the code not crash, 3.1 would have to be executed after 3.2. Though it is (to my knowledge) not possible to control this order.

The most elegant solution would be to create an `onDelete` closure in the SecondView, which would be passed as an argument.

This would also solve the architectural anti-pattern that the element view has access to all elements, not only the one it is showing.

Integrating all of this would result in the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var elementHolder: ElementHolder

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.elementHolder.elements.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                SecondView(
                    element: self.elementHolder.elements[index],
                    onDelete: {self.elementHolder.elements.remove(at: index)}
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var element: String
    var onDelete: () -> ()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(element)
            Button(action: onDelete) {
                Text("delete")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, it would even be possible to remove ElementHolder and just have a `@State var elements: [String]` variable.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear, why the app crashes: SecondView will be informed first (I tried to set breakpoints, but I couldn't figure this out). Unfortunately your solution is not what I'm searching for, because my `SecondView` needs much more other properties of the `ElementHolder`, so I can't pass just a String... that is why your code is working, because the SecondView doesn't hold the ElementHolder

Comment: ... and I have a `TextField`, not just a `Text`, please see my updated code

Comment: You could pass the item represented by each SecondView through a Binding. The binding works in two ways, so you pass the value from the ContentView to a SecondView and the SecondView passes changes back to the ContentView. Deletion would still have to be handled separately, as shown in my post. You can create a Binding using `Binding<YourValue>(get: {self.elementHolder.elements[index]}, set: { newValue in self.elementHolder.elements[index] = newValue})`. In the SecondView, there would have to be a variable `@Binding var value`.

Comment: @Lupurus Have you get any lucky? I have a same situation over here. A list contains elements and each of these elements shoudl have been binded through the views just to be able to update them in one view and publish those other views. It works like a charm without the `onDelete`

Comment: @Palle It works as it is, however when I set the `SecondView` as a destionation to `NavigationLink` it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Faruk: It doesn't work, if you use it with `.indices`. Just don't use `.indices`, you need to iterate over the elements themselves and then you have to work with `.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == element.id })`, if you want the index of each element

Comment: @Lupurus OK, but how do you update the `element` inside the view with that way?

Comment: @Faruk: With `Binding(get: { element }, set: { self.elementHolder.elements[self.elementHolder.elements.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == element.id} ?? 0] = $0 } )`

Comment: @Lupurus in the `SecondView`?