# SwiftUI .onDelete throws Fatal Error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I have list of `Account`s that each of them has a detail page and they are connected through `@Binding` in the `AccountDetailView`. Current code work well, updates are fine. No problem at all. However when I added the `onDelete` modifier to the `ForEach` below and tried `swipe to delete` gesture in app, it crashes and says `Fatal Error: Index out of range` twice.

I made some search and learned that `ForEach` somehow does not get notified -or ignores it, idk much detail- and looks for the last index of the array. In the end, it can not find it and throws the error.

```
List {
    Section(header: Text(String.empty), footer: Text(Strings.SectionFooters.accountListFooter.value)) {
        ForEach(self.accountsModel.accounts.indices, id:\.self) { idx in
            NavigationLink(destination: AccountDetailView(account: self.$accountsModel.accounts[idx])) {
                AccountRow(account: self.$accountsModel.accounts[idx])
            }
        }.onDelete { (set) in
            self.accountsModel.accounts.remove(atOffsets: set)
        }
    }
}
```

With keeping `id: \.self` parameter in place it throws the error at the `AppDelegate`, when I try to remove the parameter, the app works fine but again `onDelete` it throws the same error at `NavigationLink`'s row above.

Here is the `AccountDetailView`

```
struct AccountDetailView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var accountsModel: AccountsViewModel
    @Binding var account: Account
    @State var isEditing: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally `Account` class conforms to `Codable`, `NSObject`, `Indentifiable` and some other class. I did not want to give all the code just because did not want make the question complicated and hard to examine. If requested, I will provide any part of the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. With respect to the this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61431362/1404324) to a related question, it came clear. Apperantly, with using the `.indices` to fullfill `ForEach` makes `onDelete` not to work. Instead, going through directly `Elements` of an array and creating proxy `Bindings` is working.

To be it more clear here are the `ContentView`, `DetailView` and an extension for `Binding` to avoid cluttering view.

`ContentView`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var store: DataStore

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.store.data, id: \.id /*with or without id*/) { (data) in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(data: /*created custom initializer*/ Binding(from: data))) {
                        Text(data.name)
                    }
                }.onDelete { (set) in
                    self.store.data.remove(atOffsets: set)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("List")
        }
    }
}
```

`DetailView`

```
struct DetailView: View {

    @Binding var data: MyData

    var body: some View {
        List {
            TextField("name", text: self.$data.name)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(self.data.name)
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

`Binding` extension

```
extension Binding where Value: MyData {
    init(from data: MyData) {
        self.init(get: {
            data as! Value
        }) {
            dataStore.data[dataStore.data.firstIndex(of: data)!] = $0
        }
    }
}
```

This way, both `onDelete` and publishing changes by directly updating the object inside detail view will work.