# Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift when removing element from array

Tags: swiftui

I have a form to select some users and assign them a int value.

The model:

```
class ReadingTime: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    @State var user: User
    @Published var value: Int

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ReadingTime, rhs: ReadingTime) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    init(id: Int, user: User, value: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self._user = State(wrappedValue: user)
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

The view:

```
@Binding var times: [ReadingTime]
@State var newUser: User?

func didSelect(_ user: User?) {
    if let user = user {
        readingTime.append(ReadingTime(id: readingTime.nextMaxId,
                                       user: user,
                                       value: 0))
    }
}

// In the body:
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    HStack {
        Picker("Select a user", selection: $newUser.onChange(didSelect)) {
                    ForEach(users) {
                        Text($0.name).tag(Optional($0))
                    }
                }
                .id(users)
            }
            VStack(spacing: 8) {
                ForEach(0..<times.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    HStack(spacing: 0) {                            
                        Text(times[i].user.name)
                        TextField("ms", value: $times[i].value, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                        Button(action: {
                            NSApp.keyWindow?.makeFirstResponder(nil)
                            if let index = times.firstIndex(where: { $0 == times[i] }) {
                                times.remove(at: index)
                            }
                            newUser = nil
                        }, label: {
                            Text("REMOVE")
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

However, when deleting an entry in the list, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift

What's going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61431459/12299030? Also pay attention at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911168/12299030 description about `ForEach`?

Comment: @Asperi Thank you, I followed what you described in the 2nd link and it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 7):

Modifying the number of items of an array while being enumerated is an evil trap.

`0..<times.count` creates a temporary static range.

If you remove the first item in the array index 1 becomes 0, index 2 becomes 1 and so on.

Unfortunately there is no index `times.count-1` anymore and you get the `Index out of range` crash when the loop reaches the last index.

You can avoid the crash if you enumerate the array reversed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I perfectly understand the issue, but can you explain how to "enumerate the array reversed"?

Comment: Instead of starting at index 0 start at the last index and count backwards.

Comment: @vadian in 2023 also facing this issue. I think using `reversed()` worked for me if I delete the last element from the array. But If I delete the first element, crash happens.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no accepted answer:

Don't use the index of your array to get the specific object inside your *ForEach*. Like you did before, you're able to access your objects without using *count*. Using *count* causes your *Index out of range* error.

Do it like this:

```
ForEach(times) { time in
   // ...
   Text(time.user.name)
   // ...
}
```